Play sound notification when browser tab is inactive
Motivation: Let's assume that I have a marketplace. Let's assume that user posted advertisement/poster and went to other website to read something or watch. Still, he would like to receive sound notification to answer to potential buyer/applicant and return back to other duties. Earlier implementing this functionality was easy. Still, I was not able to find working solution in 2024.
I checked existing answers and seems that they are not working in 2024.

Playing sound from INACTIVE browser tab
Play audio in inactive tab with JavaScript

It is due to:

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

In modern browsers autoplay is disabled by default, so you can't do new Audio(src).play(). I experimented alot, but I didn't find reliable way to play sound notifications. In other modern websites it seems that sound notifications are missing in 30-50% of cases.
Question: Is it possible to play sound notification from inactive browser tab or when browser is minimized? If it is - then what is the simplest way to achieve this?

You can not auto play audio sound in recent browser. You need to have user interaction with the document. If you are sure that the user will click or scroll on the document before 'leaving' then you can use an event listener for that that will pause the audio. then when the browser is inactive you can play it again. You can use for that the event  'visibilitychange'.


let audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
let clicked = false

document.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    audio.pause()
    clicked = true
})
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.hidden) {
        console.log('Browser is inactive');
        if(clicked) setTimeout(()=>{
            audio.play()
        },10000);
    } else {
        console.log('Browser is active');

    }

})
<audio id="myAudio" src="./sound/sound.mp3"></audio>



